# Plot multiple paths in rviz

Tags: path, ros, markers

I'm trying to plot different paths at rviz

I'm using the following code to get a first approach (based on this repository: https://github.com/HaoQChen/show_trajectory/tree/master/src)

```
import rospy
import math
import numpy as np
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from nav_msgs.msg import Path, Odometry
from std_msgs.msg import Empty


class ProjectElement(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path_pub = rospy.Publisher('~path', Path, latch=True, queue_size=10)
        self.circle_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~circle', Empty, self.circle_cb, queue_size=10)
        self.line_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~line', Empty, self.line_cb, queue_size=10)
        self.project_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~project', Empty, self.project_cb, queue_size=10)
        
        self.paths = []

        self.rate = rospy.Rate(50)

    def circle_cb(self, msg):
        
        path = Path()

        centre_x = 1
        centre_y = 1
        R = 0.5
        th = 0.0
        delta_th = 0.1

        while (th<2*math.pi):
            x = centre_x + R * math.sin(th)
            y = centre_y + R * math.cos(th)
            th += delta_th

            this_pose_stamped = PoseStamped()
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.x = x
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.y = y

            this_pose_stamped.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
            this_pose_stamped.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"

            path.poses.append(this_pose_stamped)

        path.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"
        path.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
        
        self.paths.append(path)

    def line_cb(self, msg):
        
        path = Path()

        x_start = 0.0
        y_start = 0.0
        length = 2
        angle = 45 * math.pi/180
        th = 0.0
        delta_th = 0.1

        while (th<length):
            x = x_start + th * math.cos(angle)
            y = y_start + th * math.sin(angle)
            th += delta_th

            this_pose_stamped = PoseStamped()
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.x = x
            this_pose_stamped.pose.position.y = y

            this_pose_stamped.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
            this_pose_stamped.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"

            path.poses.append(this_pose_stamped)

        path.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"
        path.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()

        self.paths.append(path)  

    def project_cb(self, msg):

        while(True):
            for element in self.paths:
                # element.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
                self.path_pub.publish(element)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    rospy.init_node('path_simulate')

    elements = ProjectElement()

    rospy.spin()
```

I can visualize the paths at rviz, but I don't know how to plot both figures at the same time in this way.

[line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16M7M.png)

[circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XZ0K.png)

I would like to ask if this approach is the best way to address this issue or which could be the best way.

Comment: what's the plugin you are using in rviz to plot the path? Have you considered using two different publishers?

Comment: I'm not using any plugin, I'm displaying nav_msg/Path at rviz. In the other hand, I'm not using 2 publishers because the number of figures is dynamic (it can be more than 2 or not), I plotted only 2 as example

Comment: The built-in "Path" display in rviz only plots one path. I think you are looking for a way to plot multiple paths, but even then the question would be how rviz would know whether a newly published path on your one topic is an update to an existing path or a new one to plot -- `nav_msgs/Path` has no name or id field to distinguish them. So I think your logic is incomplete.

Comment: You might get what you want from using a pointcloud display instead. (and publishing all paths jointly accordingly)

Comment: Effectively I couldn't display multiple paths in that way, so I chose the option in the answer below. Marker ros msg has id field so that I can modify old figures and add new ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved with visualization_msgs/MarkerArray based on this question:
https://answers.ros.org/question/220898/how-to-use-rviz-to-show-multiple-planing-paths/?answer=220993#post-id-220993

I post the code used here in case anyone needs it

```
import rospy
import math
import numpy as np
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3, Point
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker, MarkerArray

class ProjectElement(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.marker_pub = rospy.Publisher('~marker', MarkerArray, latch=True, queue_size=10)
        self.circle_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~circle', Empty, self.circle_cb, queue_size=10)
        self.line_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~line', Empty, self.line_cb, queue_size=10)
        self.project_sub = rospy.Subscriber('~project', Empty, self.project_cb, queue_size=10)

        self.marker_array = MarkerArray()

    def circle_cb(self, msg):

        marker = Marker()
        marker.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP

        marker.action = Marker.ADD
        
        marker.scale = Vector3(0.01, 0.01, 0)

        marker.color.g = 1.0
        marker.color.a = 1.0

        centre_x = 1
        centre_y = 1
        R = 0.5
        delta_th = 0.1

        for th in np.arange(0.0, 2*math.pi+delta_th, delta_th):
            x = centre_x + R * math.sin(th)
            y = centre_y + R * math.cos(th)

            point = Point()
            point.x = x
            point.y = y

            marker.points.append(point)

        marker.id = 0
        marker.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
        marker.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"

        self.marker_array.markers.append(marker)

    def line_cb(self, msg):
        
        marker = Marker()
        marker.type = Marker.LINE_STRIP

        marker.action = Marker.ADD
        
        marker.scale = Vector3(0.01, 0.01, 0)

        marker.color.g = 1.0
        marker.color.a = 1.0

        x_start = 0.0
        y_start = 0.0
        length = 2
        angle = 45 * math.pi/180
        delta_th = 0.1

        for th in np.arange(0.0, length, delta_th):
            x = x_start + th * math.cos(angle)
            y = y_start + th * math.sin(angle)

            point = Point()
            point.x = x
            point.y = y

            marker.points.append(point)

        marker.id = 1
        marker.header.stamp = rospy.get_rostime()
        marker.header.frame_id = "/my_cs"

        self.marker_array.markers.append(marker)

    def project_cb(self, msg):

        self.marker_pub.publish(self.marker_array)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    rospy.init_node('markers_simulate')

    elements = ProjectElement()

    rospy.spin()
```

And the result achieved

[marker array display](https://ibb.co/PQwT5Nz)